# Where can Ubuntu snaps write data?

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

Applications packaged as snaps in Ubuntu are installed (mounted) under the `/snap/$SNAPPNAME` location. Everything under `/snap` is mounted as a read-only file system, thus applications cannot write to that space, neither in other app's directories nor in their own.

While there is a `home` [interface](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/interfaces/) that snaps can specify to read/write the user's home directory, it is reserved for security reasons and needs to be manually connected (enabled) by the user.

So where can an app inside a snap write its config, data and other files? Are there APIs to access special writeable locations?

Comment: Appears snap's can bind the home/media interface's automatically these days, FWIW...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

When you declare apps in your `snapcraft.yaml`, it results in a binary wrapper being generated upon install and placed into `/snap/bin/`, named after your package and app name (note that if the app is a service, this wrapper is instead a systemd .service file).

That wrapper contains most of the environment under which the application will run. The two environment variables that are most relevant to this question are `SNAP_DATA` and `SNAP_USER_DATA`. You can find more information about these in [the documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/environment-variables), but I'll describe them here as well:

- `SNAP_DATA` is a system-wide writable area (in `/var/snap/`). This might be used to host logs for services, for instance.
- `SNAP_USER_DATA` is a user-specific writable area in the home directory of the user running the application (specifically `/home/<user>/snap/`). This might be used for user-specific configuration files, etc.

Both of these directories are very important to the upgrade/rollback functionality, since both of them are *versioned*. That is, each revision of a given snap has its own copy of these directories. Let me explain with an example.

Say you install revision 1 of the "foo" snap. That will create two directories:

- `/var/snap/foo/1` (`SNAP_DATA`)
- `/home/<user>/snap/foo/1` (`SNAP_USER_DATA`)

Now say "foo" uses both of these. Maybe it has a service that hosts a database in `SNAP_DATA`, and a binary that uses config files in `SNAP_USER_DATA`.

Now revision 2 of "foo" is released, and it's automatically updated. The first thing that happens is that `/var/snap/foo/1` is copied into `/var/snap/foo/2` and `/home/<user>/snap/foo/1` is copied into `/home/<user>/snap/foo/2`. Then the new revision is fired up. It should notice that it's running on old data, and maybe it has some database migrations to run to the database in `SNAP_DATA`. It does that, and away it goes.

Now say those migrations fail for whatever reason, and this application needs to be rolled back. It begins using the old revision of the /snap/foo application, where `SNAP_DATA` was pointing to `/var/snap/foo/1` and `SNAP_USER_DATA` was pointing to `/home/<user>/snap/foo/1`. This picks things up on the old version at the point before the migrations were run, since those operations were run on a copy of the data.

Long story short: don't use the `home` interface to store data you can be storing in `SNAP_DATA` or `SNAP_USER_DATA`, since they're an integral part of the upgrade/rollback strategy. Take advantage of them!

**UPDATE for v2.0.10:**

Two new data directories were also introduced:

- `SNAP_COMMON` sits alongside `SNAP_DATA`, but is specifically *unversioned*. Every revision of the specific snap has access to this directory, so it's not copied upon upgrade/rollback etc. This might be used for particularly large, unversioned files (e.g. raw data that isn't really version-specific).
- `SNAP_USER_COMMON` sits alongside `SNAP_USER_DATA`, but is again specifically *unversioned*. It might be used for storing non-version-specific data per user.

**UPDATE for v2.15:**

The files placed within `/snap/bin` are no longer wrappers that define the environment, but symlinks to `/usr/bin/snap`. So the way to determine the environment under which an application runs would be to use `snap run --shell <snap>.<app>`, for example:

```
$ sudo snap install hello-world
$ snap run --shell hello-world
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

$ env | grep SNAP
SNAP_USER_COMMON=/home/kyrofa/snap/hello-world/common
SNAP_REEXEC=
SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl:
SNAP_COMMON=/var/snap/hello-world/common
SNAP_USER_DATA=/home/kyrofa/snap/hello-world/27
SNAP_DATA=/var/snap/hello-world/27
SNAP_REVISION=27
SNAP_NAME=hello-world
SNAP_ARCH=amd64
SNAP_VERSION=6.3
SNAP=/snap/hello-world/27
```

Comment: Isn't `SNAP_USER_COMMON` dir being created automatically by snapd? The launcher script in `/snap/bin/` doesn't create it, and creating it manually inside the snap fails (permission denied). Running `snap run app` creates that folder, though (but the command fails with `execv failed: No such file or directory`... I have no idea how to use that command).

Comment: Yes, it should be, but it's not (a bug that's fixed in the upcoming release where `snap run` is used).

Comment: Note that snap run is used as of v2.15.

Comment: Seem the doc updated, here the ref page https://snapcraft.io/docs/reference/env

Comment: Two years later - have you had coffee yet?  Still no documentation about where Snap applications can write data in the (virtual or host) file system.  That does not offer me great inspiration as I try to understand the basic obvious details about snaps.

Comment: I added a link to docs about the environment variables to the answer.