# What is the ~/snap folder being used for?

Tags: snap

I just noticed an empty folder called `snap` in my user's home directory. What is this folder being used for?

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762354/where-can-ubuntu-snaps-write-data/762405#762405) for more information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This directory is corresponding to `$SNAP_USER_DATA` for your snaps. This is where your snaps will be able to write versioned data under your user account. `$HOME` for your snap will be set to it as well.

You will find there:

- `~/snaps`

  - `<snap name>`

    - `<version 1>`

      data for version 1
    - `<version 2>`

      data for version 2

and so on…

Comment: CommonMark is four spaces; SE does not use GitHub markdown where backtick fencing is acceptable

Comment: What in the hell is the snap??