# Snappy Core 16 Dynamic DNS Update

Tags: dns, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, snap, dynamic-linking

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running a webserver on Ubuntu Snappy Core 16, and I'm usind dynamic DNS to address to my IP. I use [NO-IP](https://www.noip.com) for a free dynamic DNS and it requires an update every 30 days or it expires. They offer packages for their own Dynamic DNS Update Client, but as far as I know, I'm not able to install these programs with the Snappy Core. My router doesn't support this, so I can't setup it that way.

Is there a way to setup these scheduled updates with Snappy Core 16? Still a bit new with these systems so simpler solutions are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can still use their dynamic update client on Ubuntu Core, just download [their tarball](https://www.noip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz) and use the pre-built binaries out of it.

If that wasn't good enough for you, it would be incredibly easy to make a snap out of it. Create a `snapcraft.yaml` file, fill it out like so:

```
name: dynamic-update-client
version: 2.1.9snap1
summary: No-IP dynamic DNS update client
grade: stable
confinement: strict
description: |
  Dynamic DNS Update Client continually checks for IP address changes in the
  background and automatically updates the DNS at No-IP whenever it changes.

apps:
  noip2:
    command: noip2
    plugs: [network, network-bind]

parts:
  dynamic-update-client:
    plugin: make
    source: https://www.noip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
    source-subdir: noip-2.1.9-1
    artifacts: [noip2] # Otherwise it tries to configure while building
    build-packages: [gcc, libc6-dev]
    organize:
      noip2: bin/
```

and run `snapcraft` on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried to get the tarball before, but hit a wall since I didn't find a way to download it. wget is not avaliable on core 16 as far as I'm aware. Is there alternative for it?  I'll try if the snapcraft method works when I have the time.

Comment: There is a way to get classic tools on the core image, but I'm not 100% sure how on the new images (I'll check and get back to you). However, you can always `wget` on a classic machine and `scp` over.

Comment: Yes the scp  should work for my case, so I can try both solutions, if I have issues with either.

Comment: Alright, here's how you can get a classic environment on Ubuntu Core: `sudo snap install classic --devmode --edge` will get you the required snap, and `sudo classic` will get you into a new shell with the ability to use `apt`, etc.

Comment: Okay so I tried the solutions and didn't get far. It seems that I'm unable to do this without enabling the classic mode.  

Solution 1: I installed the classic mode and required packages to make the install. However I didn't manage to do this this way as it errors when I try to build it.  

`(classic)myusername@localhost:/usr/local/src/noip-2.1.9-1$ sudo make` 


gcc -Wall -g -Dlinux -DPREFIX=\"/usr/local\" noip2.c -o noip2 
noip2.c:136:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'noip2' failed
make: *** [noip2] Error 1

Comment: Solution 2: I was able to create and install the snap, but I can't get it running because I'm unable to configure it. myusername@localhost:~$ dynamic-update-client.noip2 Can't locate configuration file /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf. (Try -c). Ending! myusername@localhost:~$ sudo dynamic-update-client.noip2 -C -c noip2.conf Auto configuration for Linux client of no-ip.com. Can't create config file (noip2.conf) Permission denied

Comment: You shouldn't have to compile the tarball-- just use the precompiled binaries out of the `binaries` directory. Also, snaps are very confined regarding where they can write files, see [Where can Ubuntu snaps write data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762354/where-can-ubuntu-snaps-write-data) for more information. You might have to customize the snap a little to your needs.