# copy config file from $SNAP to $SNAP_COMMON is not working with classic confinement

Tags: snap

As suggested in this "[Where can Ubuntu snaps write data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762354/where-can-ubuntu-snaps-write-data/762405#762405)"

I tried Option[1] for my app which is working fine for **devmode confinement**.
But the same is *getting failed when i tried to change the confinement form devmode to classing mode*.
Any reason why this is getting failed for classic confinement.
If needed i can share you my code with you which will help you to understand the issue.

Thanks & I appreciate any suggestion here!!

Comment: what exaclty are you looking for? snap settings location?

Comment: what exactly my snap will do is that schedule the system reboot based on the parameter present at $SNAP_COMMON/config file, and to copy the config file from $SNAP path to $SNAP_COMMON path i wrote a shell script in **hooks/install file** (run once after snap installed) and for reboot i have created a service which will continuously monitor the config file and reboot the system accordingly and for that  snap should have classic confinement .